# list environment on glossary definition doesn’t work

Tags: glossaries, paralist

I try to put an `inparaenum` environment on a glossary definition like this :

```
\newglossaryentry{polymo}%
{%
  name={Lorem},
    description={Lorem ipsum dolor
    \begin{inparaenum}[i)]
      \item sit amet
      \item et adiqui
    \end{inparaenum}
},
plural={polymorphisms}
}
```

But it give me this output:

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1409678912.png))</sub>

So, this is my AWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb,french,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\longnewglossaryentry{lorem}%
{%
  name={Lorem}
}%
{%
consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse%
    \begin{itemize}%
      \item lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum u
      \item Aenean ut orci vel massa suscipit pulvinar. Nulla sollicitudin. Fusce varius.
    \end{itemize}%
}

\author{Me}
\title{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\date{This day}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  Ut velit mauris, egestas sed, gravida nec, ornare ut, mi.
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Aenean ut orci vel massa suscipit pulvinar.
    \item Nulla sollicitudin.
    \item Fusce varius, ligula non tempus aliquam, nunc turpis ullamcorper nibh
  \end{itemize}


  \glsaddall
  \glossarystyle{index}
  \printglossary[title=Glossaire,toctitle=Glossaire]

\end{document}
```

I compile it with `xelatex main.tex; makeglossaries main ; xelatex main.tex` and I get the following result:

[image: IMG]

As you see, I you `itemize` environment out of glossary definition and it work correctly.

There is a way to force a correct output of `inparaenum` in glossary?

Edit: I find it isn’t only the case with `inparaenum` but the glossary definition general not work with list environment.

Comment: Did you try with the inline lists of the `enumitem` package (`enumerate*`)?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) rather than a code fragment. The problem may well depend on the glossary style that you're using. (The default style uses the `description` environment, some styles use `longtable`, some set `\hangindent`.)

Comment: I add the preamble and the command witch print the glossary Nicola. Do you find this sufficient?

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) should be a short self-contained document that can be copied, pasted and compiled to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention getting an error message, but for completeness after the glossary is created there's an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

The problem is that the `index` style isn't compatible with entries that contain `list`-based environments. The `index` style is analogous to the style typically used to display an index (via commands such as [`makeidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeidx)'s `\printindex`) which does `\let\item\@idxitem` at the beginning of the scope. You need to switch to a style that's compatible with `list`-based environments. For example, changing the style from `index` to `list` produces:

[image: Image of resulting list glossary]

or using the `tree` style produces:

[image: Image of resulting tree glossary]

Comment: Thank you for this wool explanations :)
I prefer `tree` because I have parent and children definitions witch didn’t correctly work with `index`.